# Services 3: Setting taxonomy terms on node creation/update

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services, 8

For a custom node type, I have defined a field that is to hold an unlimited number of values from a taxonomy vocabulary that I defined.

This is what it looks like:

```
[field_taxonomy] => Array
  ( [und] => Array
      [0] => Array
        ( [tid] => 13 )
      [1] => Array
        ( [tid] => 14 )
      [2] => Array
        ( [tid] => 15 )
  )
```

This is the JSON I pass to the server during node creation (as per [1]):

```
'field_taxonomy':
  { '11':
    { 'tid': '11'} }
```

This format is accepted (i.e. no 406, which I get if I try to mirror the above structure), but when I look at the node on the server, the field does not contain any terms.

What does my request have to look like so I can succesfully set taxonomy terms on a node?

[1] [What will be the post parameter when specifying vocabulary term?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44715)

Answer (score 3):

Your request should use the following:

```
"field_taxonomy":{ "und": { "values": "14" }  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood from [Services Documentation](http://drupal.org/node/1354202) you doesn't need to create ершы sequence in the array [0],[2] etc. The Services module numbers it itself.

Also, if you are using auto complete for taxonomy you should use the term id, tid, 3 times

```
"field_taxonomy":  [{
  "tid":{
    "tid":"[tid:11]",
    "tid":"[tid:12]",
    "tid":"[tid:13]"
        }
}]
```

Comment: I'm not using autocomplete, but checkboxes for the vocabulary items. After a few hours of trial and error and a few glances at the Services source code, I was able to POST my vocabulary items in the following format:

`"field_taxonomy": {
"und": [
11
]
}`

Comment: But this `"field_taxonomy": { "und": [ 11 ] }` doesn't work at all in my case http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/47589/10671

Comment: What does _ершы_ in "you doesn't need to create ершы sequence" mean?

Comment: "this" - it was a russian keyboard layout

Comment: In D7, a taxonomy term reference field with the autocomplete widget uses JSON like this: `"field_tags":{"und":"Foo"}"` When it is an autocomplete, the term name needs to be used instead of the term id.

Comment: And for multiple values using an autocomplete widget, you can send: `"field_tags":{"und":"Foo,Bar"}` - This works both for creating new terms and using existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that tripped me up:

If you've created an autocomplete field for your term reference using a view, instead of passing in the term name like:

```
"field_vocab_tags": {
      "und": [
          {
             "target_id": "40"
          }
      ]
  }
```

You need to pass in the complete term title *according to the view*. In my case, I have the title set as:

```
Term Title - my_unique_id_field (tid)
```

so I actually have to set:

```
"field_vocab_tags": {
      "und": [
          {
             "target_id": "My Term Title - UNIQUE_ID_23 (40)"
          }
      ]
  }
```

This is specifically in the case where you have an autocomplete using views, and the view formats the title as I did above.

If you want multiple references, simply add additional arrays in your field[und] array, like so:

```
"field_vocab_tags": {
      "und": [
          {
             "target_id": "My Term Title - UNIQUE_ID_23 (40)"
          },
          {
             "target_id": "My Next Term Title - UNIQUE_ID_24 (41)"
          },
          {
             "target_id": "Your Term Title - UNIQUE_ID_C (42)"
          }
      ]
  }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I used a string as tag values:

```
"field_tags": {
   "und": "term 1, term 2"
 }
```